# Alternate colors in quiver plots

Tags: pgfplots

I am experimenting to find a good way to do a 3d vector field plot of a magnetic field of a thin wire. One idea was to use a different color for each fixed z value. I just tried to use cycle list, but this doesn't seem to work with quiver plots. How can I make it work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-10:10,
    samples=10,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    zmin=-10,zmax=10,
    cycle list name=color,
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-10,-5,5,10}{
      \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}
      \addplot3[quiver,-stealth,
      quiver={
        u={-y/(x^2+y^2},
        v={x/(x^2+y^2)},
        w={0},
        scale arrows=10
        },
      ]
      (x,y,#1);
    }
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,-12) -- (0,0,12);
    %\fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (-1,-1,0) rectangle (1,1,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `colored=mapped color` (and some `point meta`, if needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-10:10,
    samples=10,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    zmin=-10,zmax=10,
    point meta=z,
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-10,-5,5,10}{
      \addplot3[quiver,-stealth,
      quiver={
        u={-y/(x^2+y^2},
        v={x/(x^2+y^2)},
        w={0},
        scale arrows=10,
        colored=mapped color
        }, 
      ]
      (x,y,#1);
    }
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,-12) -- (0,0,12);
    %\fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (-1,-1,0) rectangle (1,1,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously you can play with the colormap and `point meta`.