# Clip path in 3d plot

Tags: pgfplots

This is a follow up question to [Alternate colors in quiver plots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534534/4011)

How can I clip the regions of the drawn circles (instead of drawing circles):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-10:10,
    samples=20,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    zmin=-20,zmax=20,
    point meta=z,
    height=20cm,
    width=15cm,
    view={45}{45}
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-20,0,20}{
      \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}
      \draw (0,0,#1) circle (7);
      \addplot3[quiver,-stealth,
      quiver={
        u={-y/(x^2+y^2)},
        v={x/(x^2+y^2)},
        w={0},
        scale arrows=10,
        colored=mapped color
      }, 
      ]
      (x,y,#1);

    }
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,-20) -- (0,0,20);
    % 
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way. Use `scope`s and parametric plots for the clipped paths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-10:10,
    samples=20,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    zmin=-20,zmax=20,
    point meta=z,
    height=20cm,
    width=15cm,
    view={45}{45}
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-20,0,20}{
     \begin{scope}
      \clip plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,domain=0:355] ({7*cos(\t)},{7*sin(\t)},#1);
      \addplot3[quiver,-stealth,
      quiver={
        u={-y/(x^2+y^2)},
        v={x/(x^2+y^2)},
        w={0},
        scale arrows=10,
        colored=mapped color
      }, 
      ]
      (x,y,#1);
      \end{scope} 
    }
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0,-20) -- (0,0,20);
    % 
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This way is safe and works to the best of my knowledge with all versions of pgfplots that are currently around. Some of the versions do not work with `circle(7)`, and `circle[radius=7]` does not project the circle to the plane you want it to project.